# Radio Button changeImage (Multiple IDs?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have this little function, where the image changes on a radio button selection and it works fine.

Now the problem is, I want the function to be available for a second "image-slider". Problem is, the image of the first slider changes when I use the radio-buttons of the second one (of course, because they are the same ID.) I tried to apply multiple IDs like this:

```
function changeImage(imgName) {
     image = document.getElementById('image1', 'image2');
     image.src = imgName;
}
```

... but that didn't work.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/v4phdL3p/4/)

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML**:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" name="image1" id="image1">
<br>
<input type="radio" name="image1" onclick="changeImage('http://placehold.it/100x100',this);" checked>
<input type="radio" name="image1" onclick="changeImage('http://placehold.it/200x200',this);">
<input type="radio" name="image1" onclick="changeImage('http://placehold.it/300x300',this);">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" name="image2" id="image2">
<br>
<input type="radio" name="image2" onclick="changeImage('http://placehold.it/100x100',this);" checked>
<input type="radio" name="image2" onclick="changeImage('http://placehold.it/200x200',this);">
<input type="radio" name="image2" obj.name onclick="changeImage('http://placehold.it/300x300',this);">
```

**JS**:

```
function changeImage(imgName, obj) {
    image = document.getElementById(obj.name);
    image.src = imgName;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4phdL3p/5/)**